# Yii2 console app: how to detect runtime environment?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

Say I have a PHP Yii2 console app, run in command line, like this

```
/var/www/my_app/yii myconsole/action
```

When I deploy the app in my production server (run as a cronjob), I have problem looking for an elegant way to detect if the app is running in my local machine or in production server.

When it is a web app, setting an environment variable in VirtualHost is a great solution. But for console app, right now I can use `php_uname()` function to differentiate environment by machine name, are there any better ideas for this?

Answer (score 2):

See [The official documentation for Environmental Constants](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#environment-constants)

Basically, check your index.php file to see which YII_ENV is defined, and you can then call it globally

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're right, but the console app still has an [entry script](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-entry-scripts.html#console-applications) where this variable is defined. Remember how you run console commands (`yii something/something`). That `yii` is your entry script.

Comment: Yes we can define constants in `yii` entry point, but I need a way for Yii console app to automatically detect current environment, and based on that detected environment, set those variables.

Comment: Automatically based on what? how would Yii2 figure out what environment you are using? the yii entry script is the equivalent of index.php and you should set the environment variable there. See the advanced template and how environments are set up, both index.php and yii are not in the main repository, but they are installed by php init.